# Resolution of foreign key for related domain object fail (obj.relatedId)

Tags: grails, foreign-keys, grails-orm

Foreign key resolution for related domain object stopped working (.i.e object.relatedId), sample:

Domain model:

```
class Order { Customer customer }
```

In grails/sh console:

```
order = Order.last()
order.customer.id   // prints: 677
order.customerId    // previously working well
```

> ERROR groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:
>   customerId for class: Order Possible solutions: customer

```
order.properties.each { k, v -> print "${k}:${v}\n" }  // prints: customerId:null
```

It has worked before and somehow stopped for any domain object

Versions:

> Groovy Version: 2.4.4 JVM: 1.8.0_51 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS:
>   Linux Grails version: 2.3.9

Is someone had similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does Grails 2.3.9 support Java 8?  Officially I understand Grails 2.4 is the start of support for Java 8 and I found Grails 2.5.0 is needed for Java 8 support using the Intellij IDE.  Have you tried Java 7 instead of 8?

Answer (score 0):

On second thought try changing both your variable name and your domain object name to something other than order.  I had a problem like that once where the name caused conflict and order could be a special name?